# Instalar apache versión 2.4.25 (2.4.6 actual) en Centos 7

Tags: linux, apache, instalacion, centos7, actualizacion

He intentado instalar la versión de apache 2.4.25 en Centos 7, solo muestra error que ya existe la última versión, y  no es posible actualizar versión o instalar

Comment: ¿Qué resultado obtienes de `yum list httpd`? Inclúyelo en tu pregunta.

Comment: Recuerda que CentOS Linux a diferencia de CentOS Stream prefiere estabilidad sobre actualización.

Answer (score 0):

Pacere ser que quieres hacer un downgrade

```
$ sudo yum downgrade <package_name>-<version_info>
```

Con esta sintaxi tendria que funcionarte.

mas informacion:
https://access.redhat.com/solutions/29617